# Alter menu title Django-cms

Tags: django, django-cms

what I want to do is to create a custom `menu.html` take the `{{ child.get_menu_title }}` and only use the first letter in the string that `{{ child.get_menu_title }}` outputs.

I would imagine that I have to extend the `menu_tags.py` somehow to create my own function for this purpose. But I'm completely lost in which file and how and what I should do to make this work.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could override the [get_menu_title()](https://github.com/divio/django-cms/blob/develop/menus/base.py#L45) but better dont touch core things. instead use the [slice](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#slice) template filter

```
{{ child.get_menu_title|slice:':1' }}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CMS_MENU_TITLE_OVERWRITE` = `True` in your settings.py file.

This function allows you to overwrite the default menu title of any cms page easily through the Django admin. It will show you an additional field next to the default title field in the admin which you can modify with anything you want.

You can check this function in the [Django CMS documentation](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/2.4.0/getting_started/configuration.html): Item 3.6.2.